# Java - difference in char something = 0; on Linux and Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, encoding

I've got a problem - this code on Windows returns:

```
UTF-8
>> <<
```

code:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class CharQuestion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char zeroChar = 0;
        String start = ">>";
        String end = "<<";

        String str = String.format("%s%c%s", start, zeroChar, end);

        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());

        System.out.print(str);
    }

}
```

but the same code on Linux returns only

```
UTF-8
>>
```

Can you help please to find out why?
Thank You

Comment: Outputting a NUL character to a console should be considered implementation defined (depends on the console)

Comment: It's also possible the underlying function of print actually considers that internal NUL character as an end terminator (likely if Java interpreter is written in C)

Comment: If you pipe stdout to a file, is the null byte present in the file?

Comment: The title is misleading.  This Java code behaves in exactly the same manner on all platforms.  “Difference in printing '\0' to console on Linux and Windows” would be a more appropriate title.